# Integration of elementary function by shortest possible method.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int {\frac{1}{x^\frac13+x^\frac14}+\frac{log(1+x^\frac16)}{x^\frac13+x^\frac12}}dx$$
I have to sovle this function integral.
Please help me out I have tried a lot but its approach is very long. I have also seen its solution bit still its quite long approach. Please suggest the shortest possible method.

Note: The solution should also be in elementary form.

Comment: Are you sure you've copied it accurately?  integrals.wolfram.com gives something very  ugly and non-elementary.

Comment: Yes that's the question. I have copied it correctly and it's only elementary function.

Comment: Four halves and six halves?  Why not just write $2$ and $3$?

Comment: The result contains non-elementary functions (the first term does not, but the second does). Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I have picked up this problem from elementary function integration topic so don't worry the question is in elementary functions .

Comment: Nope, the second part is non-elementary. It will typically involve the dilogarithm function $\text{Li}_2$.

Comment: Error 504: Question missing context.

Comment: I hope you won't get in trouble if not being able to find a primitive in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: The question is picked from A. Das Gupta Problems Plus in IIT Mathematics. You can just Google the book if you have a doubt. I also have the solution but its very long and is elementary form and I just want a shortest possible method.

Comment: Please post the final answer so that it is proved I'm wrong.

Comment: $$12\left[\frac{z^8}{8} -\frac{z^7}{7} +\frac{z^6}{6} -\frac{z^5}{5} +\frac{z^4}{4} -\frac{z^3}{3} +\frac{z^2}{2}-z\right] +12\log(z+1) +6\left[\frac13\times\alpha\times e^\alpha -\frac19\times e^\alpha -\frac32\times e^\alpha2 +\frac34\times e^2\alpha +3\alpha\times e^\alpha -3e^\alpha -\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right] +\text{constant}$$

Comment: Where $z=x^{\frac{1}{12}}$ and $\alpha = \log(1+x^3)$.

Comment: I have now entered every possible form of that expression that I can guess, and differentiated, and the result has not been close to the original function. Please update your question with the correct expression. Be careful when you write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29713/discussion-between-adesh-tamrakar-and-mickep).

Comment: OK, so now the question has changed considerably. It now has an elementary primitive, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For the first part**, write
$$
\frac{1}{x^{1/4}+x^{1/3}}=\frac{1}{(1+x^{1/12})x^{1/4}}
$$
and then let $u=x^{1/12}$. Using a geometric sum, you end up with
$$
12\int \frac{u^8}{1+u}\,du=12\int -1+u-u^2+u^3-u^4+u^5-u^6+u^7+\frac{1}{1+u}\,du.
$$
which is easy to integrate. I leave it to you.

**For the second part**, write
$$
\frac{\log(1+x^{1/6})}{x^{1/3}+x^{1/2}}=\frac{\log(1+x^{1/6})}{(1+x^{1/6})x^{1/3}},
$$
and then let $u=x^{1/6}$. You end up with
$$
6\int\frac{u^3\log(1+u)}{1+u}\,du.
$$
Let $s=\log(1+u)$, and you will find (again, modulo constant),
$$
6\int (e^s-1)^3s\,ds.
$$
This is easily calculated, integrating by parts.

Comment: well excellent job and thank you very much. But still expecting any short method.